Reverse an easing function
I'm trying to make an exponential slider where it increases values slowly at first and ramps up towards the end. I used an easing function to convert a linear value by applying a ease-in-quad function.
For example, say a slider starts at 200 and goes till 500 and user moves the slider to the center. The linear value at 50% would be 350. I calculate the percentage progress of the slider - in this case 50% and I apply my function on it
let t = 50,
    b = 200,
    c = 150, // 350 - 200
    d = 100;

return c * (t /= d) * t + b; // 237.5

This is all good. But the problem is, elsewhere I need to convert this value of 237.5 back to 350. I tried reversing the calculation but I need both t and c. If I have one, I'll know the other.
I also tried running an ease-out-quad on it but that didn't work either
let t = 18.75, // 200 + 18.75% = 237.5
    b = 200,
    c = 37.5, // 237.5 - 200
    d = 100;

return -c * (t /= d) * (t - 2) + b; // 212.74

The answer is not what I was expecting. Is this even possible to do?



function easeInQuad(t, b, c, d) {
    return c * (t /= d) * t + b;
}

function reverseEaseInQuad(y, b, c, d) {
    return d * Math.sqrt((y - b) / c);
}

const forward = easeInQuad(50, 200, 150, 100);
const reversed = reverseEaseInQuad(forward, 200, 150, 100);

console.log(JSON.stringify("Forward : "+forward));  // 237.5
console.log(JSON.stringify("Reversed : "+reversed)); // 50




Did you mean to write reverseEaseInQuad(237.5, 200, 150, 100)? In any case, I don't have access to the 150 figure when reversing.
